# Resource recommendations for Crossed product in C*algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I am taking the course crossed product C*-Algebras as reading course. Could anyone recommend me some resources for studying on my own? Lecture notes or books, both are apprecited.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following Master's thesis helpful (the author appears to be a PhD student at Alberta right now):

Olowule Victor Olobatuyi. Crossed products of C*-algebras. M.Sc. thesis,
University of Windsor. 2013. Available at: http://scholar.uwindsor.ca/etd/4855/

One of the sources in Olobatuyi's bibliography is a book of the same title by Dana Williams, available from the AMS website or a good math library:

Crossed Products of $C^{*}$-Algebras. AMS, 2007. http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-134

There is also some information, in the context of noncommutative geometry, in

Masoud Khalkhali and Matilde Marcolli (eds.) An Invitation to Noncommmutative Geometry. http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6422

I hope this helps!